# Get all combinations from list values

Tags: python, list

I'm using `python 2.7` and I have this list:

```
new_out_filename = ['OFF_B8', 0, 'ON_B8', 1, 'ON_B16', 4, 'OFF_B0', 7]
```

I want to get all the combinations of the strings like `OFF_B8_vs_ON_B8`, `OFF_B8_vs_ON_B16`, `OFF_B8_vs_OFf_B0`, `ON_B8_vs_ON_16`, etc.

Is there an easy way to achieve it?

I tried something like:

```
for k in range(0, len(new_out_filename), 2):
    combination = new_out_filename[k]+'_vs_'+new_out_filename[k+2]
    print combination
```

But my list is out of index and also I don't get the appropriate result.

Can you help me please?

Comment: see in your example when k reaches 6 your program searches for new_out_filename[8] which will lead to out of index

Comment: @NimishBansal Yes you are right. However my code solution is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: you could learn about from itertools import combinations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just use `combinations` on a sliced list to ignore the numbers:

```
import itertools
new_out_filename = ['OFF_B8', 0, 'ON_B8', 1, 'ON_B16', 4, 'OFF_B0', 7]
for a,b in itertools.combinations(new_out_filename[::2],2):
    print("{}_vs_{}".format(a,b))
```

result:

```
OFF_B8_vs_ON_B8
OFF_B8_vs_ON_B16
OFF_B8_vs_OFF_B0
ON_B8_vs_ON_B16
ON_B8_vs_OFF_B0
ON_B16_vs_OFF_B0
```

or with comprehension:

```
result = ["{}_vs_{}".format(*c) for c in itertools.combinations(new_out_filename[::2],2)]
```

result:

```
['OFF_B8_vs_ON_B8', 'OFF_B8_vs_ON_B16', 'OFF_B8_vs_OFF_B0', 'ON_B8_vs_ON_B16', 'ON_B8_vs_OFF_B0', 'ON_B16_vs_OFF_B0']
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much! That's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I just added extra for loop and it is working.

```
new_out_filename = ['OFF_B8', 0, 'ON_B8', 1, 'ON_B16', 4, 'OFF_B0', 7]
for k in range(0, len(new_out_filename), 2):
    sd  = new_out_filename[k+2:] #it will slice the element of new_out_filename from start in the multiple of 2 
    for j in range(0, len(sd), 2):
       combination = new_out_filename[k]+'_vs_'+sd[j]
       print (combination)
```

> output:
>
> OFF_B8_vs_ON_B8
>
> OFF_B8_vs_ON_B16
>
> OFF_B8_vs_OFF_B0
>
> ON_B8_vs_ON_B16
>
> ON_B8_vs_OFF_B0
>
> ON_B16_vs_OFF_B0

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what the problem was and how your code fixes it.